# Is it possible to repopulate lactase in the stomach?

Tags: enzymes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can an adult without genetic lactase persistence still develop a tolerance for dairy foods?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/107/can-an-adult-without-genetic-lactase-persistence-still-develop-a-tolerance-for-d)

In my younger years, I don't seem to have a problem drinking milk.

Nowadays, when I drink milk, I keep farting away.

After searching around the Internet, [this site](http://www.dairycare.sg/resource_faq.htm) claimed that it is due to lactose intolerance. They have a product that claims to be able to repopulate the enzymes in the body so that it can digest milk. Is this product based on sound principles?

Can someone (other than the Dairy Care company itself) refute or support its claims?

Thanks!

Comment: Although the other question is not specific to this product, the answer does answer your question.

Comment: I think the other question answers this and is a better written question.

Comment: How does "repopulating the lactase enzyme" and "tolerating milk" mean the same thing?

Comment: If you read the answers you will see they describe essentially the technology which is in the product you asked about. The supplemented lactobacteria produce the lactase enzyme, and the tech fundamentally is sound. Whilst the question isn't worded the same, the answer you're looking for is there. Anyone answering this question would basically be repeating all the info in those answers.